# Define difference between keyboard lag and hardware failure - acer nitro

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, lag

I have been suffering for over a year with the keyboard of my acer AN515-52 in windows 10. The problem is very annoying and seems to be quite common at least in acer notebooks (https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/546438/some-keys-are-working-intermittently-on-acer-aspire-a515-51g). In my keyboard, the keys that work when they want are: s, 0, 7, 4, k, o, backspace and ctrl. All the other keys never fail. I was quite sure that the problem was somehow related to hardware, but one thing was intriguing. The problematic keys never work after a reboot, but after couple of seconds (in bad day almost a minute) crazily pressing them, they would mysteriously start to work again. However, they would fail intermittently after that and for sure would be off after couple of seconds without any typing (Then, the crazy pressing would make they work again). Moreover, if I keep pressing `s`, once it appears on the screen all the other problematic keys will work as well (at least until they fail again, leading me to the circle of suffering). Thus, the fallibility of these keys seems to be related. If one work, all work, if one fail, all fail.

After trying several different solutions described on the internet, such as (i) disabling filter keys, (ii) restore health, (iii) reinstalling keyboard driver, I stumbled in a quite promising solution: modify the registry/HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response

My bet was that the keyboard had a key-specific lag, therefore it could be fixed by decreasing the AutoRepeatDelay and Flags. In fact, the problem improved A LOT by modifying that, but it still fails quite frequently. This is my current configuration:

[image]

I got quite significant improvement by increasing the keyboard response in such way, but I am wondering if someone managed to find a configuration that fix this problem completely. I was told several times that if an external keyboard works it should be hardware. However, I have this strong feeling that this is just some kind of key-specific lag (otherwise, why a change in configuration would improve this problem?). Moreover, a lot of people reported problems even after replacing the keyboard in acer notebooks with similar problems. I would be glad to receive insights on this issue!

Comment: This does look like a hardware issue, and you _should_ try connecting an external keyboard. Changing the sensibility by software could help by making it recognize key presses so short that they would have otherwise been deemed 'noise'. Still, it seems broken.

Comment: I disagree with you. That's my whole point. I have tested external keyboard already and it does not fail. However, as explained above, there are patterns that point to another direction. I have decreased the number in Flags and I am working for more than a hour without problems. It is quite clear to me that is not just a broken keyboard. If you want to contest that please explain the strange patterns that I describe.